# What are the asymptotic running times for OWL EntitySearcher methods (eg. EntitySearcher.getAnnotations(c, o, factory.getRDFSLabel()))

Tags: owl, ontology, asymptotic-complexity, protege, owl-api

I am writing an application which makes use both of an ontology/owlapi and a sqlite database in which the value of certain fields is an IRI from the ontology.

I'm wondering whether it would be (asymptotically) quicker to retreive the rdfs:Label and rdfs:Comment annotations from the SQL DB (assumeing they are stored there in advance) rather than retrieve those values from the OWLAPI every time.

In general, how time/space intensive are the main operations in EntitySearcher (asymptotically, or otherwise)?

Assume for this example that rdfs:label is the only annotation property belonging to class c, so we don't have to explicitly iterate through a list of annotation properties.

Comment: the source code is online...and it is basically just using Java streams, e.g. `annotations.filter(ax -> filter(p, ax)).map(ax -> ax.getValue());` thus, if you really need some O notation, I guess it's just `O(n)' with n being the number of annotation axioms or maybe all axioms.

Comment: Close. Axioms are indexed in various ways, but the indexes are lazy - axioms by axiom type is created eagerly; Axioms by entity - and therefore annotation axioms - is done lazily, so the first request costs more, but follow up requests are fast.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done a complete analysis of the relevant code here, but roughly speaking the operations involved are:

- Given an ontology and an entity
- get annotation axioms for entity
- iterate looking for matching annotation property
- get the literal value

The axioms are indexed by type, so getting the annotation axioms is O(1). Selecting the axioms relevant for an entity also leverages an index, so that's O(1) again.
Iterating through and looking for a matching property is O(N) where N is the number of annotations - 1 in your example, so again O(1). The comparison itself resolves in a string comparison for the property IRI. `rdfs:label` itself is a singleton, as it is used a lot, so the comparison is insignificant in performance.
Extracting the literal value is a simple access, so overall the process should be O(1).

Comparing to a database, O order would be the same; but the default OWLAPI implementation is `ConcurrentHashMaps` in memory. Access to a remote database over the network, assuming there's no need to open a new connection, is still likely to dominate the actual time measurements.